# Trying to implement $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement simple http service in AngularJS by fetching data from an api in json format. its a blog post and i am trying to show it in my blog. The data is received in my console but is not displaying in my blog. Please help. It uses Bootstrap in the front end. Here is a screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWji1.jpg

```js
var a = angular.module('Blog', []);
a.controller('BlogControl', function($http) {
  var b = this;
  this.heading = 'My Angular Blog';
  this.subheading = 'Made by Anurag';
  this.baseurl = 'https://projectsapi.edwisor.com/api/blogs/';
  $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: this.baseurl + "all"
    })
    .then(function Success(response) {
      console.log(response);
      this.bpost = response.data.data;
    });

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Blog">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>My Angular Blog</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->


</head>

<body ng-controller="BlogControl as newBlog">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Header -->
  <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
  <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1>{{newBlog.heading}}</h1>
            <hr class="small">
            <span class="subheading">{{newBlog.subheading}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="post-preview" ng-repeat="bl in newBlog.bpost">
          {{bl.bodyHtml}}

        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- Pager -->
        <ul class="pager">
          <li class="next">
            <a href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>



  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

  <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Important JavaScripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not the instance of the controller inside the callback. Try to capture it outside and then assign `bpost` on the captured instance:

```
var that = this;
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: this.baseurl + "all"
})
.then(function Success(response) {
    console.log(response);
    that.bpost = response.data.data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does this happen though? this seems to work in all other scenarios but not here?

Comment: The AJAX callback is asynchronous, it has different context than the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

try this npm module [anngularjs-requester--http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-requester--http)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use that, it's the exact same functionality wrapped in methods.  Plus, it introduces a global `url` variable.